# Taking backup for Jenkins jobs as well as plugins

Tags: jenkins

I am using Ubuntu14.04, installed Jenkins and configured jobs by installing some plugins.
I want to know if there is any efficient way to take backup of all plugins and jobs.

Edit: Also want to know how to restore the backup.

Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this path in your installation /opt/app/jenkins/var/lib/jenkins ,  This is the location where all your Jenkins data is stored. You can write a backup strategy for the contents of this folder to be purged.

Also take a look at this [article](http://jenkins-ci.org/content/keeping-your-configuration-and-data-subversion) from experts.

Alternatively you can also use the [SCM SYNC Configuration plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SCM+Sync+configuration+plugin)

To answer your question as a whole, the approach i listed in the first will help you restore the files on the system and all that you need is to restart Jenkins and you shud have restored the system fully. This approach gives you full insurance in a collapse of your particular jenkins instance.

Answer (score 0):

Thin backup named plugin is given, which do the backup/restore work very smoothly.